# How to develop a solution in limit without L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{\ln x}\right).$

I don't know how to remove $\infty-\infty$ uncertainty in the question. Please explain it and how many different solution can we do in the question?

Comment: @copper.hat I put a picture link into sentence.You can look at it

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hôpital's rule? (The rule can be repeated as necessary.)

Comment: Actually I can solve it with L'Hopital but how can we solve it with limit rules?

Comment: @Atakan: Limit does not exist check by $x\to 1^-$ and $x\to1^+$.

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: there is situation in my country,L'Hopital was removed in the limit so I can develop extra solutions for this questions with your help :)

Comment: @YadatiKiran are you sure it does not exist?

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan: Yeah. as $x\to1^-$ we have $+\infty$ and $x\to1^+$ we have $-\infty$

Comment: @Atakan: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean that you cannot use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @YadatiKiran solution is showed "∞" in the book.

Comment: I checked on SymboLab and it gives $-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Atakan: The two sided limit does not exist.

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan: Can you show how you get $\frac{-1}{2}$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes,we cannot use L'Hopital in the limit questions

Comment: @copper.hat: I suppose the OP is asking to evaluate without using L'Hopital Rule.

Comment: @YadatiKiran. I used L'Hopital but evaluated incorrectly. The answer below is correct

Comment: There must be $42$ solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use Taylor Series expansions.

$\displaystyle\lim_{m\to0}\frac1m-\frac1{\ln(1-m)}, m=1-x$

$=\displaystyle\lim_{m\to0}\frac1m+\frac1{m+\frac{m^2}2+\frac{m^3}{3}...}=\displaystyle\lim_{m\to0}\frac1m(1+\frac1{1+\frac m2+\frac{m^2}3...})$

which diverges to $-\infty$ when $m\to0^-\implies x\to1^+$, and $+\infty$ when $m\to0^+\implies x\to1^-$.

[image]

Comment: Ohh,I liked your solution and I'm supposing the book is wrong about shown answer.Because your solution is looking true

Comment: The graph of $\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{\ln x}$ supports my observation.

Comment: how did you prove it on the graph?Can you show it on the graph?

Comment: thank you for showing it :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @Atakan You might want to note that this limit doesn't possess the $\infty-\infty$ form. Both the terms $\frac1{1-x}$ and $-\frac1{\ln x}$ diverge to $+\infty$ when $x\to1^-$ and to $-\infty$ when $x\to1^+$. So, it is actually the $\infty+\infty$ form.

Comment: yes I realized it when you say,then the book says the answer is ∞.does your words confirm the book?Or do I think wrong?

Comment: It doesn't have the $\infty-\infty$ form, but your book has the wrong answer

Comment: okay I got it,you are saying it doesn't have the ∞-∞ form, thank you again Shubham

Answer (score 2):

Write ${1 \over 1-x} - {1 \over \log x} = {\log x +x-1\over (1-x) \log x}$.

The Taylor expansions are
$\log x +x-1 = 2(x-1)+\cdots$ and  $(1-x) \log x = -(x-1)^2+ \cdots $.

Hence we expect the behaviour for $x$ close to $1$ to be $\approx -{2 \over x-1}$.

Comment: Actually I couldn't understand what you mean,can you write as more detailed?

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor expansion?

Comment: no,I'm not familiar :(

Comment: Certain functions can be expanded around a point in the form $f(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} f^{(k)}(x_o) (x-x_0)^k$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series.) This expansion can be used to approximate the local behaviour of $f$. In this case, I am approximating the numerator and denominator by Taylor series, and the leading (non zero) terms dictate the quotient's behaviour.

Comment: okay, I'm trying to understand it

Answer (score 2):

I want to rewrite the limit slightly:

$$\lim_{x\to1} \left(\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\right) = -\lim_{x\to1} \left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)} + \frac{1}{x-1} \right). $$

Note that now our two summands have the same sign when $x<1$ and when $x>1$. The limit from the left goes to $(-\infty)+ (-\infty) = (-\infty)$ and the limit from the right goes to $\infty + \infty = \infty$. Thus, the limit does not exist.

No indefinite forms needed!

Comment: Yes,you solved it with small changes but it's looking true ,thank you for your solving :)

Comment: That's the best solution in my opinion! Simple and clever.

Answer (score 2):

We have that by $y=x-1 \to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to1} \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\dfrac{1}{\ln x}\right) =\lim_{y\to0} \left(-\dfrac{1}{y}-\dfrac{1}{\ln (1+y)}\right)$$

and by standard limits since $\frac{\ln(1+y)}y\to 1$

$$-\dfrac{1}{y}-\dfrac{1}{\ln (1+y)}=-\dfrac{\ln(1+y)+y}{y\ln (1+y)}=-\dfrac{\frac{\ln(1+y)}y+1}{\ln (1+y)}\to \begin{cases}-\infty\quad y\to 0^+\\\\+\infty\quad y\to 0^- \end{cases}$$

Comment: $+\infty$ when $y\to0^-$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yes indeed I lost a minus sign in the last step and reverse the result! Thanks so much for pointing out that!

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the first term should have been $\frac{1}{x-1}$ rather than $\frac{1}{1-x}$. In the former case the substitution $x=e^t$ reduces the problem to the evaluation of 
$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)=-\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^t-1-t}{t(e^t-1)}=-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^3)}{t^2+O(t^3)}=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}. $$
The Maclaurin series of $e^t$ is either a trivial consequence of the series definition of $e^t$ or a simple consequence of the dominated convergence theorem / integration by parts:
$$ e^t-1-t = t^2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)e^{tx}\,dx \to t^2 \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\,dx = \frac{t^2}{2}.$$